# I must use OpenAl for ogg files

Tags: android, development-environment, wav, openal, ogg

I can use openAl for .wav files in Android developing.I can set Position for .wav files.But unfortunately I think openAl does not support .ogg or .mp3 files.Only supported .wav files. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use OpenAl for ogg. Take a look into this [example](http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=56.0)

Comment: Thanks for your support. i found something at : http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.0